# Oracle: can I avoid a lot of JOINs?

Tags: oracle

I have the following tables in Oracle 12c:

- `objects` (about 600 K lines)
- `attributes` (about 10 M lines)

I need to transpose objects' attributes into another table. The idea is shown in the picture below.

To do so now I use a lot of "JOINs" like:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.name,
    a1.value as attr_1,
    a2.value as attr_2,
    a3.value as attr_3,
    a4.value as attr_4,
    a5.value as attr_5
FROM objects o
LEFT JOIN attributes a1 ON a1.obj_id = o.id AND a1.attr_id = 1
LEFT JOIN attributes a2 ON a2.obj_id = o.id AND a2.attr_id = 2
LEFT JOIN attributes a3 ON a3.obj_id = o.id AND a3.attr_id = 3
LEFT JOIN attributes a4 ON a4.obj_id = o.id AND a4.attr_id = 4
LEFT JOIN attributes a5 ON a5.obj_id = o.id AND a5.attr_id = 5
```

I have some queries with up to 20 attributes so I have to JOIN "10 M lines"-table 20 times.

It works but it takes a lot of time.

Do you have any good ideas how to organize it better?

[image]

Comment: What about the Oracle PIVOT?

Comment: As I understood from the documentation PIVOT gives values from the table as a field names. But I need to define field names according to my own rule. Moreover PIVOT is mostly oriented on using aggregative functions which are not perfect for my case. This is just my opinion. Let me know if it's possible to solve my case with PIVOT.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you are dealing with an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) data model.  Which is one of the worst designs ever foisted on the database world.  For a good take on EAV, see https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/  ... Actually it looks like you are starting with an EAV design, and trying to get to a more rational, relational table.  One would hope this is a one-time effort to get away from EAV.  I'll leave the solution to those with more experience doing so.

Comment: In all honesty, I do think a billion joins is the cleanest way to write this. Like @EdStevens said, this is a god-awful data-model for writing queries, but if you're stuck with it, I think any other solution is going to wind up over-complicating things (and become an absolute mess to maintain).

Comment: @JoshEller It's really not the best way.  Using GROUP BY and CASE to pivot the data, as shown in my answer, is a time-worn tradition.  To those unfamiliar with it, it is probably not immediately as obvious as the multi-join method, but the performance gain should be well worth it.

Comment: @DaveCosta I guess it's a judgement call either way. I can immediately understand what OP's code is meant to do, whereas it takes a couple seconds to figure out what yours is doing (yours is certainly easier to write in the first place though). Maybe it's just because I'm just not familiar with the pattern you're using, but if I was a new developer being brought on to maintain a 10 year old project with no documentation, I'd have an easier time working with the billion `joins`.

Comment: Also, is it definitely a given that each object will have at most one attribute of each type?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility, as mentioned in comments, is to use the PIVOT option on the SELECT.  I am not clear what your concern is about this -- are you just saying you want to determine the actual resulting column names yourself? You can easily alias the columns after the PIVOT operation.

Before PIVOT existed, the standard method I used and saw others use to accomplish it was like this:

```
SELECT obj_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN attr_id = 1 THEN value ELSE NULL) AS attr_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN attr_id = 2 THEN value ELSE NULL) aS attr_2,
       ... etc. ...
FROM attributes
GROUP BY obj_id
```

For the full query, you could put this subquery in a CTE and join that with `objects`.

Note this doesn't necessarily mean that Oracle will execute the entire subquery before doing the join.  In your case it might, since I assume every row in `objects` has corresponding rows in `attributes`.  But if you had a filter on `obj_id` in the query, it might filter on that first then do the grouping.  In any case, I'd certainly expect this to be more efficient than joining many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use level and connect by to generate the SQL like below.But if you give the exact SQL skeleton we can make use of user_tab_Cols to generate the SQL.

```
   SELECT 'select o.id,o.name, 'sql_text
    FROM   dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a.'
           ||LEVEL
           ||'.values as attr_'
           ||LEVEL
           ||',' sql_text
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FROM objects o '
    FROM   dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LEFT JOIN attributes a'
           ||LEVEL
           ||' ON a'
           ||LEVEL
           ||'.obj_id = o.id AND a'
           ||LEVEL
           ||'.attr_id = '
           ||LEVEL
    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```